# .net failed to load assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServicesEnum

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, ssis

It is a vb.net with regular windows forms, some showing charts thru report builder. Application calls SSIS packages and processes a chosen data mining model programmaticly. This message pops up when a client tries to run data mining model... I don't know what I am missing. SQL is 2012 and visual studio is 2012 also. Client machine is a 64 bit windows7. All database objects are in dbo schema and client has the owner privileges to that schema. Client can do everything including viewing charts except processing any data mining structure.

[image]

Comment: Does the Client machine have SQL Server installed?

Comment: No, not on the client machine but they are on the same network and he has other applications reaching out the sql server, they run with no problem.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your problem? I have a related problem with the same missing assembly.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get back to you earlier, I was out of the country this summer and just got back. Unfortunately, I couldn't solve this problem. We ended up not using DataMining for our predictions but I would appreciate a comment here if you were able to figure that out for future reference.